# What does Array.BinarySearch mean when it says an array with negative indexes?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

[The documentation for `Array.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .NET says that it does not work for an array that has negative indexes. As far as I know, .NET only has arrays with positive indexes and you are not allowed to inherit from the `System.Array` type.

Why does the documentation state this and how is it possible?

> This method does not support searching arrays that contain negative indexes. array must be sorted before calling this method.

Comment: You can create array with any lower bound you want, just not obvious in C#. Check out http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/12/22/make-arrays-with-non-zero-lower-bounds-in-c.aspx, or search for more - http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+array+negative+lower+bound

Comment: `var negativeIndexesArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof (int), new[] {10}, new[] {-5});`

Comment: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/41349

Comment: You must realize what the documentation is for. The doc is for .NET, not C# specifically. Negative indexes is a completely legitimate thing in C++ which is also referenced in the linked ref.

Comment: Also in C#, such arrays can occur when you interop with a COM component.  Albeit that the more typical mishap is their first element is at index 1.

Comment: @DanielCook I actually considered that. At that point though, it is a pointer not an Array type in .NET which is the parameter required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an array that lets you supply negative indexes to your array:

```
var grid = (int[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int),new[] {7,7}, new[] {-3,-3});
for (int r = -3 ; r <= 3 ; r++) {
    for (int c = -3 ; c <= 3 ; c++) {
        grid[r,c] = 10+r + c;
    }   
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/gbZrAa)

You can make an array with a single dimension, too, but you wouldn't be able to convert it to `int[]` because CLR uses a special type for one-dimension arrays. However, you could use such array with negative indexes through the `Array` API. The documentation says that you are not allowed to pass such arrays to the `BinarySearch` method.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to create an `Array` with negative indexes in .NET, using this overload of  [`Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) factory method, where you can specify the lower bound of the index:

```
public static Array CreateInstance(
    Type elementType,
    int[] lengths,
    int[] lowerBounds
)
```

A 1-dimensional array with length of 10 and index starting at -10:

```
var a = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), new[] { 10 }, new[] { -10 });
a.SetValue("test", -5);
Console.WriteLine(a.GetValue(-5));
Console.WriteLine(a.GetLowerBound(0));

// yields:
// test
// -10
```

Also note that a 1-dimensional array with negative index lower bound cannot be cast to a *vector*, such as `int[]`, which must be 0-based indexed. This kind of array is of different type than vector or 0-based indexed array:

```
Console.WriteLine((Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new[] { 1 }, new[] { -1 })).GetType());
Console.WriteLine((Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new[] { 1 }, new[] { 0 })).GetType());
Console.WriteLine((new int[] {}).GetType());

// yields:
// System.Int32[*]
// System.Int32[]
// System.Int32[]

(int[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new[] { 1 }, new[] { -1 })

// throws:
// System.InvalidCastException
```